# React Native MQ with Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, react-native, message-queue, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-js

I'm looking for some advice on how to set up a MQ system using Azure Service Bus with React Native. I'm trying to set up a (food) ordering system, but I'm facing a few problems.

For Azure Service Bus to work, the Azure Service Bus SDK is recommended. Sadly, as of right now the Azure JS SDK does not support React Native yet ([as seen here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/5771)). The alternative solution is to either [bundle the SDK myself](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/documentation/Bundling.md) (which could theoretically work). Or, make calls to the REST-API of Azure (though I couldn't find a clear documentation on receiving the messages that the client is subscribed to).

Now I tried bundling the SDK myself, but sadly I just couldn't get that to work. Also I read the ASB REST API documentation (see reference) but couldn't find a clear way to receive the messages (most likely cause the REST API is mostly meant for *managing* the ASB).

Any idea how I could solve this?

Also: is there a way to have a MQ without a connection string? Kinda similar like how you could use SignalR with JWT to check whether a user is allowed to subscribe to a certain queue/topic? (= in SignalR considered a 'Group')

*the reason SignalR doesn't suffice in this scenario is because SignalR doesn't ensure that a message is received, so if the client (order taking tablet) loses connection, it would also lose an order*

References:

- [Azure Service Bus REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/)

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have a similar problem and I'm looking for a message bus that I can use with React Native